# Deploy Meteor to GoDaddy Linux Shared Hosting

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, meteor, deployment

I'm working with a client who already has a hosting plan set up for his site and building a web app for him in Meteor JS.
I usually use digital ocean for all of my hosting needs, but it seems as I'm stuck with his shared plan for now.

Is there a way I can deploy this meteor app to the shared Linux plan?
I know the digital ocean way is to use MUP but I'm not sure if that's an option with a shared server.

Thanks guys.